# How to get content using httpAgilityPack website?

Tags: html, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, html-agility-pack

I have a link:http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/appeal

Now, I want to get content from this link and I want to get that's results:"a request to the public for money, information, or help".

Source of page:

```
 <span class="def-head">
        <span class="def-info"></span>
        <span class="def">

            a 

            <a class="query" title="request" href="http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/request"></a>

             to the 

            <a class="query" title="public" href="http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/public"></a>

             for 

            <a class="query" title="money" href="http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/money"></a>

            , 

            <a class="query" title="information" href="http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/information"></a>

            , or 

            <a class="query" title="help" href="http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/help"></a>

            : 

        </span>
    </span>
```

How do that???
I'm developing on windows phone 8.1 runtime.

Comment: How about using their API (http://dictionary-api.cambridge.org/) instead of getting yourself banned for doing it the hard way?